# Mathematical Formula

Tags: java, formula

I have to build a sequence like

```
(amount-(amount/36*1)) + 
(amount-(amount/36*1 + amount-amount/36*2)) + 
(amount-(amount/36*1 + (amount-amount/36*2) + (amount-amount/36*3))) +
(amount-(amount/36*1 + (amount-amount/36*2) + (amount-amount/36*3) + (amount-amount/36*4))) + 
...
(amount-(amount/36*1 + (amount-amount/36*2) + (amount-amount/36*3) + (amount-amount/36*4) + ... + (amount-amount/36*n)))
```

where `n` is a value I will be calculating separately based on how many calendar months have passed since when an event took place.
The formula should go on in the above fashion till the value of `n` is met.

I can't think of how to iterate so that the formula builds

Comment: why are you first off not storing 36 as a variable? And it seems to me something you could solve by recursion

Comment: Is `amount/36*n` supposed to be `(amount/36)*n` or `amount/(36*n)`? Also, from the third line onwards the bracketing is weird. Should `(amount-(amount/36*1 + (amount-amount/36*2) + (amount - amount/36*3)))` be `(amount - (amount/36*1 + amount - (amount/36*2 + amount - amount/36*3)))`?

Comment: I've formatted the formula to see it clearer, but I've left the brackets as you wrote it. I think you may want to review them now and make sure they're correct.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the formula correctly this should work `calc(amount, 0, 1, n)`:

```java
public double calc(double amount, double sum, int curr, int n) {
       if (curr > n) return 0;
        sum += (amount - amount / 36 * curr);
        return sum + calc(amount, sum, curr + 1, n);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use recursion probably, not sure if this is the right thing that you want. Probably you can get an idea from below solution and do it yourself.

```
public double calculate(double amount, int N){
  double total = 0;
  if(N==0){
    return total;
  }
  for(int i=1;i<=N;i++){
    total + = (amount - amount/(36*i));
  }
  return calculate(amount, N-1) + total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below [recursive](https://www.baeldung.com/java-recursion) formula should make the trick (even though you should probably review the operations, as I don't really get them from the brackets you put):

```
private static double sumUpToN(double amount, int n) {
    double result = amount;
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        result += (amount - amount/36*j);
    }
    return n > 0 ? result + sumUpToN(amount, n-1) : result;
}
```

You call your formula like this:

```
double test = sumUpToN(100, 3);
```

It will happen that:

#### Starts with `n == 3`

It computes `result = 100 + (100-100/36*1) + (100-100/36*2) + (100-100/36*3) = 383.33333333333337`
Then it takes this value and it adds it to:

#### Goes to `n == 2`

It computes `result = 100 + (100-100/36*1) + (100-100/36*2) = 291.6666666666667`
Then it takes this value and it adds it to:

#### Goes to `n == 1`

It computes `result = 100 + (100-100/36*1) = 197.22222222222223`
Then it takes this value and it adds it to:

#### Goes to `n == 0`

It just returns `100`. If you don't want this last step to happen, change the `return` condition from `n > 0` to `n > 1`.

#### Return result

The sum of all these (`972.2222222222223`) should make the formula you're searching.

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate all of your help and I went with  1000-1000/36*((initial_date -final_date)+1.
That is giving me correct results.